# How to fetch initial value using useState() before the component is mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The variables in the Context are initialized using useState(function) which gets a value when the function returns a value. This value is then accessed by components of the applications. The problem here is that the component is mounted and then the data is fetched instead I want it to fetch the data before the component is rendered.

My Context store

```
function AuthContextProvider(props){
      var s;
      const fetchData=()=> {
      userSession.getFile('st.json')
         .then((file) => {
          s= JSON.parse(file || "")
          setState(s
         )
        })
        return s
    }

   const [userType,setState]=useState(s)
```

index.js

```
function Auth () {
  const {userType} =useContext(AuthContext)
  const auth=()=>{
    if (userSession.isSignInPending()) {
      userSession.handlePendingSignIn()
      .then((response) => {
       if({userType}==="Hire"){window.location.href = "/dashboard";}

        else if({userType}==="Dev"){
            window.location.href = "/dashboard";
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = "/profilef";
            }
       });
      }

  }

  return null;
```

Here the condition is executed and then the data is fetched from useState()
instead I want it to fetch the data and then execute the conditions

Comment: you cant do that, because the component will render while running an async process. Instead just return null in the component until the data is loaded. `if(!userType) { return null }` put that right before you return jsx

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

Comment: What if my function already has a return null statement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Use async await & useEffect

Inittialized userType as '' (empty string)

```
function AuthContextProvider(props) {
  const [userType, setState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const file = await userSession.getFile('st.json');
      const s = JSON.parse(file || "");
      setState(s);
    }
    fetchData();
  },[]);
  return userType;
}
```

Comment: You should wrap userSession.getFile inside the useEffect call in an async function.  


    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        const file = await userSession.getFile('st.json');
        const s = JSON.parse(file || '');
        setState(s);
      }
      fetchData();
    )};